# How can I prevent the browser screen from scolling to the top when I do an ajax request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

My ajax is working nicely.

I have a big table of bookmarks (http://www.railslinks.com) and I can verify an individual link.  When I do that I put a spinner up and then I replace it with Verified or Unverified.  This is working well.

The only downside is that when I click on verify for one of my links that is "3 pages down", the screen element is updated correctly - but then the screen scrolls back up to the top of the page.  How could I have the screen not scroll and just keep the focus where it is?

My js is:

```
$(function(){
  $("a[data-verifying-link]='yes'").click(function(){
    // spinner here
    a=$(this).parent();
    a.html('verifying...');
    var id= $(this).data("id");
    var row = $(this).data("tableRow");
    $.ajax({
      url: "/verify_link/"+id+"&table_row="+row,
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(r) {
                $("span#verify_link_"+row).html('<span class="done">Verified</span>');
             },
       error: function(r) {
           $("span#verify_link_"+row).html('<span class="undone">Unverified</span>');
        }
    }); 
  }); 
});
```

Could the issue possibly be related to js I have which puts me on the search field at the top of the page when I visit it?

That is:

```
$(function(){
$("input[type='text']:first").focus();
});
```

which is referenced in my manifest:

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js://= require default_on_first_input_field
```

My controller has the following method used by the ajax call.

```
  def verify_link
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    if @link.valid_get?
      if @link.update_attribute(:verified_date, Time.now)
        render nothing: true, status: 200
      else
        render nothing: true, status: 422
      end
    else
      render nothing: true, status: 422
    end
  end
```

Comment: This may help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Comment: Instead of freezing your scroll up event, you can just block the particular element or whole page while making ajax call. It will prevent user to click or interrupt ajax call.

Comment: Thanks RAJ!  Could you describe that in a little more detail (code level).  Especially that would handle the success/failure state (text becomes Verifed or Unverified depending on return code) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to cancel the event:

```
$(function(){
  $("a[data-verifying-link]='yes'").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // spinner here
    a=$(this).parent();
    a.html('verifying...');
    var id= $(this).data("id");
    var row = $(this).data("tableRow");
    $.ajax({
      url: "/verify_link/"+id+"&table_row="+row,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(r) {
        $("span#verify_link_"+row).html('<span class="done">Verified</span>');
      },
      error: function(r) {
        $("span#verify_link_"+row).html('<span class="undone">Unverified</span>');
      }
    }); 
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault is your friend in this case:

```
$(function(){
  $("a[data-verifying-link]='yes'").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    .........
```